# Highchart Single Legend to control Multiple chart

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have used high chart to present the data. Currently I have one chart that shows montly, yearly, week data and another chart is for 24 hours. What I want is to have a single legend that controls both chart. While googling for solution I found this http://jsfiddle.net/teEQ3/ which seems to be working but as I am naive to javascript I can figure out how to implement this code in my running script.

here is my javascript code for chart1

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
              var buttons = Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems;
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'mylineChart',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                        spacingLeft : 60,
                        zoomType: 'x'

                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'TPV Line Chart Data',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                     rangeSelector:{
                        enabled:true,
                        buttons: [{
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1m'
                      }, {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 6,
                        text: '6m'
                      }, {
                        type: 'year',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1y'
                      }, {
                        type: 'all',
                        count: 1,
                        text: 'all'
                      }],
                        spacingBottom: 40
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: '',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                       gridLineWidth: 0,
                        type: 'datetime',
                     dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                                month: '%b %e, %Y',
                                year: '%Y'
                             }

                    },
                    credits: {
      enabled: false
  },
     yAxis: [<?php echo join($ylabel, ',') ?>],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            color: 'white',
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: -60,
            itemHiddenStyle: {
            color: "#777"
        },
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 5,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },

       exporting: {
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                exportButton: {
                    text: 'Download',
                     theme: {
                        fill: '#eee',
                        stroke: '#fff',
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                fill: '#fff',
                                stroke: '#eee'
                            },
                            select: {
                                fill: '#ddd',
                                stroke: '#0f0'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    _titleKey: 'contextButtonTitle',
                    // Use only the download related menu items from the default context button
                    menuItems:buttons.slice(2)
                },
                printButton: {
                    text: 'Print',
                     theme: {
                        fill: '#eee',
                        stroke: '#fff',
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                fill: '#fff',
                                stroke: '#eee'
                            },
                            select: {
                                fill: '#ddd',
                                stroke: '#0f0'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    _titleKey: 'printChart',
                    onclick: function () {
                        this.print();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [<?php echo join($arr, ',') ?>],
                }
                <?php
                $i = 0 ; 
                $check_temperature = "SELECT * FROM temperature_setting WHERE device_key = '".$session_row['device_key']."'";
                $ans = $conn->query($check_temperature);
                while($check = $ans->fetch_assoc()){
                    $check_temp_id = $check['temp_id'];
                    $check_is_active = $check['is_active'];

                for ($j = 1; $j <=15; $j++){
                if($check_temp_id == 'temp'.$j.'' && $check_is_active == 1){
                ?>
                myfunction(<?php echo $i++; ?>, 'lineData/tempdata<?php echo $j; ?>.php');

                <?php } 


                } 
            }

                $check_pulse = "SELECT * FROM pulse_setting WHERE device_key = '".$session_row['device_key']."'";
                $ans2 = $conn->query($check_pulse);
                while($check2 = $ans2->fetch_assoc()){
                    $check_pulse_id = $check2['pulse_id'];
                    $check_is_active = $check2['is_active'];

                for ($k = 1; $k <=8; $k++){
                if($check_pulse_id == 'pulse'.$k.'' && $check_is_active == 1){
                ?>
                myfunction(<?php echo $i++; ?>, 'lineData/pulsedata<?php echo $k; ?>.php');

                <?php } 
            }

            }


                $check_volt = "SELECT * FROM volt_setting WHERE device_key = '".$session_row['device_key']."'";
                $ans3 = $conn->query($check_volt);
                while($check3 = $ans3->fetch_assoc()){
                    $check_volt_id = $check3['volt_id'];
                    $check_is_active = $check3['is_active'];

                 for ($v = 1; $v <=4; $v++){
                if($check_volt_id == 'volt'.$v.'' && $check_is_active == 1){

                ?>
                myfunction(<?php echo $i++; ?>, 'lineData/voltdata<?php echo $v; ?>.php');
                <?php } 
                }

            }
                ?>





                function myfunction(ind, some_file) {
                    jQuery.get(some_file, null, function(tsv) {
                    var lines = [];
                    traffic = [];
                    try {
                        // split the data return into lines and parse them
                        tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
                        jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
                            line = line.split(/\t/);
                            date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');
                            traffic.push([
                                date,
                                parseInt(line[1].replace(',', ''), 10)
                            ]);
                        });
                    } catch (e) {  }
                    options.series[ind].data = traffic;
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
 }

            });
</script>
```

for chart 2

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var mychart;
            $(document).ready(function() {
               var buttons = Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems;
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'box',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                        spacingLeft : 60,
                        zoomType: 'x'

                    }, title: {
                        text: 'TPV Line Chart Data',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },

                    subtitle: {
                        text: '',
                        x: -20
                    },

                    xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickInterval: 3600 * 1000, // one hour
                    tickWidth: 0,
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    labels: {
                      align: 'center',
                      x: -3,
                      y: 20,
                      formatter: function() {
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.value);
                      }
                    }
                  },

                    credits: {
      enabled: false
  },

     yAxis: [<?php echo join($ylabel, ',') ?>],

        legend: {
            color: 'white',
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: -60,
            itemHiddenStyle: {
            color: "#777"
        },
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 5,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },/*
         plotOptions: {
            series: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function (event) {
                        var XYZ = $('#mylineChart').highcharts(),
                            series = XYZ.get(this.options.id); //get corresponding series

                        if (series) {
                            if (this.visible) {
                                series.hide();
                            } else {
                                series.show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
      */
       exporting: {
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                exportButton: {
                    text: 'Download',
                     theme: {
                        fill: '#eee',
                        stroke: '#fff',
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                fill: '#fff',
                                stroke: '#eee'
                            },
                            select: {
                                fill: '#ddd',
                                stroke: '#0f0'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    _titleKey: 'contextButtonTitle',
                    // Use only the download related menu items from the default context button
                     menuItems:buttons.slice(2)
                },
                printButton: {
                    text: 'Print',
                     theme: {
                        fill: '#eee',
                        stroke: '#fff',
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                fill: '#fff',
                                stroke: '#eee'
                            },
                            select: {
                                fill: '#ddd',
                                stroke: '#0f0'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    _titleKey: 'printChart',
                    onclick: function () {
                        this.print();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [<?php echo join($arr, ',') ?>],
                }
                <?php
                $i = 0 ; 
                $check_temperature = "SELECT * FROM temperature_setting WHERE device_key = '".$session_row['device_key']."'";
                $ans = $conn->query($check_temperature);
                while($check = $ans->fetch_assoc()){
                    $check_temp_id = $check['temp_id'];
                    $check_is_active = $check['is_active'];

                for ($j = 1; $j <=15; $j++){
                if($check_temp_id == 'temp'.$j.'' && $check_is_active == 1){
                ?>
                myfunction(<?php echo $i++; ?>, 'lineData/hourly_tempdata<?php echo $j; ?>.php');

                <?php } 


                } 
            }

                $check_pulse = "SELECT * FROM pulse_setting WHERE device_key = '".$session_row['device_key']."'";
                $ans2 = $conn->query($check_pulse);
                while($check2 = $ans2->fetch_assoc()){
                    $check_pulse_id = $check2['pulse_id'];
                    $check_is_active = $check2['is_active'];

                for ($k = 1; $k <=8; $k++){
                if($check_pulse_id == 'pulse'.$k.'' && $check_is_active == 1){
                ?>
                myfunction(<?php echo $i++; ?>, 'lineData/hourly_pulsedata<?php echo $k; ?>.php');

                <?php } 
            }

            }


                $check_volt = "SELECT * FROM volt_setting WHERE device_key = '".$session_row['device_key']."'";
                $ans3 = $conn->query($check_volt);
                while($check3 = $ans3->fetch_assoc()){
                    $check_volt_id = $check3['volt_id'];
                    $check_is_active = $check3['is_active'];

                 for ($v = 1; $v <=4; $v++){
                if($check_volt_id == 'volt'.$v.'' && $check_is_active == 1){

                ?>
                myfunction(<?php echo $i++; ?>, 'lineData/hourly_voltdata<?php echo $v; ?>.php');
                <?php } 
                }

            }
                ?>



                function myfunction(ind, some_file) {
                    jQuery.get(some_file, null, function(tsv) {
                    var lines = [];
                    traffic = [];
                    try {
                        // split the data return into lines and parse them
                        tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
                        jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
                            line = line.split(/\t/);
                            date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');
                            traffic.push([
                                date,
                                parseInt(line[1].replace(',', ''), 10)
                            ]);
                        });
                    } catch (e) {  }
                    options.series[ind].data = traffic;
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
 }

            });
</script>
```

This is what I am getting currenlty
[image: Chart1]
[image: Chart2]

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple if you're reading the API documentation well.
All you have to do is to make the series ID's the same with the other chart and let the second chart legends handle the control. See below:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container1').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
 
        series: [{
            id: 'someId',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        },{
            id: 'someId_',
            data: [30.0, 51.5, 206.4, 529.2, 44.0, 76.0, 335.6, 148.5, 216.4, 294.1, 92.6, 60.2]
        }]
    });
    $('#container2').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function (event) {
                        var XYZ = $('#container1').highcharts(),
                            series = XYZ.get(this.options.id); //get corresponding series
            
                        if (series) {
                            if (this.visible) {
                                series.hide();
                            } else {
                                series.show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            id: 'someId',
            name: 'Series 1',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        },{
            id: 'someId_',
            name: 'Series 2',
            data: [30.0, 51.5, 206.4, 529.2, 44.0, 76.0, 335.6, 148.5, 216.4, 294.1, 92.6, 60.2]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container1" style="height: 300px"></div>
<div id="container2" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: thnx for answer I know your ans is correct instead of   $('#container1').highcharts({     I am using this   $(document).ready(function() {
              var buttons = Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems;
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'mylineChart',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                        spacingLeft : 60,
                        zoomType: 'x'
                        
                    },

Comment: I'm not sure how you will do it and I can't reproduce it from my end as well as your code includes PHP codes. But all in all, that's how you do it, just follow the same thing

Comment: yeah thats the condition , anyway thnx for ur support. If you got any idea about how to convert  $(document).ready(function() { var buttons = Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menu‌​Items; var options = { chart: { renderTo: 'mylineChart', defaultSeriesType: 'line', spacingLeft : 60, zoomType: 'x' },  into  $('#mylineChart').highcharts it would be of great use.

Comment: @metalhead101 you can update your question, create a sample of your work which we could run and so we could modify it from our end. provide a sample data for the chart as well, that would be easy for us to provide a solution that you really want.